# Bluetooth Low energy best energy consumation strategy

Tags: bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am going to develop a small device with TI CC2540 inside. It will communicate with iPhone4s.
The device is designed to receive commands from iPhone and make specific actions on it.
Most of time the device is idle (99% of time).
But at any time (in case of iPhone request), it can be able to receive commands from iPhone: 1 command per 20 second with 40bytes max size.

The device should be standalone and work as long as possible.

I see here 2 decisions:

1. Device - Central, iPhone - Peripheral. The device implements Central GAP role and always scans for advertising packets from iPhone. Then device initializes connection and then iPhone begins to send commands.

2.Device - Peripheral, iPhone - Central. The device always sends advertising packets.

What is the best low energy consumption strategy?
How long will it work? 
What is the best idle strategy for BLE?
Can I implement the 1 way with new iOS6 BLE features?

Answer (score 1):

Make your device the peripheral.  The power consumption will heavily depend on your latency requirements.  How much delay between user action on phone and device reaction is acceptable?  That requirement drives the advertising duty cycle you'll need.

Comment: Delay between user action on phone and device reaction is about 300ms. The requirement about advertising is the device can be connected from iPhone at any time.

Comment: Is it correct that advertising in Peripheral mode use less energy opposite to scanning in Central mode?

Comment: The duty cycles of both advertising and scanning are configurable.  But to send advertisements, radio just turns on briefly to do a quick Tx/Rx.  When scanning, the Rx is turned on for a relatively long time because you don't know at what time or on which frequency advertisements will arrive.  So radio activity is less to do advertising than scanning.